# Persistent memory in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I could really use some hash tables to speed up searches. I would be using a custom hash table class written in C++/CLI that is thread safe. The access would be almost exclusively read-only and I estimate they would take up some ~300MB of memory.

Now the trouble is, ASP.net tends to forget things like global variables every now and then. Is there a way to make sure that a shared object doesn't get destroyed no matter what? Or alternatively destroyed as rarely as possible? My hash table class is immediately operable after creation (since it's 100% backed on disk) but its still wasted performance as it loads itself fully into memory again in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not ASP.NET forgetting global variables. A static class member will exist so long as the process it was created in exists.

The problem comes about because IIS will recycle the application pool worker processes periodically (and thus destroy global variables).

You can change IIS settings to control when a application pool is recycled. A quick Google search will give you instructions on configuring the frequency of the recycling.

I would not recommend disabling it entirely (if at all possible) as it serves a useful purpose but you will be able to make it less frequent.

If you want total control on when the hashtable is destroyed then host the hastable in your own process (potentially a Windows Service) and access it from ASP.NET using named pipes or some other IPC mechanism.

That way you can control exactly when the hashtable will be destroyed as you will control when to restart this process.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a routine in `Global.asax Application_start` to initialize your table and stored it on the cache or some kind of custom cache, this functions is called every time the app is restarted or recycled.